# How to undo bzr mv --auto

Tags: bazaar

After doing a `bzr mv --auto` a deleted file and a new file have been incorrectly picked up as a moved file, and now show up as renamed under `bzr status`. How can I change this so that the new file is marked as new again (and the deleted as deleted)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given:

```
$ bzr status
renamed:
  a => b
```

you would need to do:

```
$ bzr mv b a
b => a
~$ mv a b
$ bzr add b
adding b
$ bzr status
removed:
  a
added:
  b
```

Comment: I was hoping for better really, but I guess it is what it is - thanks

Comment: That could be simpler: `bzr rm b --keep; bzr add b`. Don't forget `--keep`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple `revert` on the file.

Note that this will revert the rename, but also the modification you made inside, so be careful !

[image]

Comment: That unfortunately is not an option. You would lose the new file!

Comment: Arghh, you are right! I've made the test and the file is really deleted :(